# Create a probability list which sums up to one

Tags: python, numpy

I use the `numpy.random.choice method` to draw a sample from a list.

The entries in the list are short dicts and look like

```
{'name': 'SomeName', 'strength': 0.75},
{'name': 'SomeName', 'strength': 0.25},
...
```

I want to use the *'strength' value (between 0 and 1)* as a probability indicator.

To use 
`drawResults = choice(data, drawCount, p=resultProb)`

I have to create the resultProb list which has to **sum up to 1**

So I came up with a function:

```
def makeProbabilities(data) -> list:
    probResult = []

    totalScore = sum(item['strength'] for item in data) # calculate in sum of all 'strength' values

    for item in data:
        if item['strength'] > 0:
            value = (100.0/totalScore)*item['strength'] #how much is this strength in relation to the total
            value2 = (1.0/100)*value                    #how much is the result above in relation to 1

            probResult.append(value2)
        else:
            probResult.append(0.0)

    return probResult
```

That seems to work, it just have a very small rounding error on the result (the sum is like 1.0000000001) but the numby.choice method does accept it.

But I have the strong impression that this solution is a bit awkward, un-pythonique and perhaps not very efficient on large data sets.

I am just discovering python so I am a bit lost with all the information concerning this language.

Any feedback on that is very welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Binary floating point numbers cannot represent most numbers exactly,
a small error cannot be avoided when computing the sum of probabilities:

```
>>> probs = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
>>> sum(probs)
0.9999999999999999
```

For more information, see

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) on Stack Overflow,
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Actually one can see in the source code of [mtrand.pyx](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1144) that this rounding error is cared for in the `choice()` function:

```
        atol = np.sqrt(np.finfo(np.float64).eps)
        # ...
        p = <ndarray>PyArray_ContiguousFromObject(p, NPY_DOUBLE, 1, 1)
        pix = <double*>PyArray_DATA(p)
        # ...
        if abs(kahan_sum(pix, d) - 1.) > atol:
            raise ValueError("probabilities do not sum to 1")
```

An error is only raised if the sum differs from `1.0` by more than
some “machine epsilon.”

We also  see  that NumPy uses the
[Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)
to add the probabilities, an algorithm which significantly reduces the
numerical error. I don't know if NumPy publicly exposes the Kahan summation
(I could not find it). But it is not difficult to implement, here is a 
version from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Kahan_summation#Python):

```
def kahansum(input):
    summ = c = 0
    for num in input:
        y = num - c
        t = summ + y
        c = (t - summ) - y
        summ = t
    return summ
```

which would then be used as

```
totalScore = kahansum(item['strength'] for item in data)
```

Example:

```
>>> probs = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
>>> sum(probs)
0.9999999999999999
>>> kahansum(probs)
1.0
```

The computation of the `probResult` array can be simplified. First note that

```
value = (100.0/totalScore)*item['strength']
value2 = (1.0/100)*value
```

is equivalent to

```
value2 = item['strength'] / totalScore
```

and that would work for the case `item['strength'] == 0` as well:

```
for item in data:
    value2 = item['strength'] / totalScore
    probResult.append(value2)
```

And now you can replace the loop with a list comprehension:

```
def makeProbabilities(data) -> list:
    totalScore = kahansum(item['strength'] for item in data)
    return [ item['strength'] / totalScore for item in data ]
```

Finally note that according to the Python naming conventions, function
and variable names should be “snake case”: `make_probabilities`, `total_score`.

Comment: `sum(p for p in probs)` => `sum(probs)` is enough :). As is `probs = [.1] * 10`

Comment: @hjpotter92: Indeed `sum(props)` is much better! (As you can see, Python is not my first language :)

Comment: Very useful thank you. Actually numpy exposes the (kahan)sum function. `print("Sum test: {} - {}".format(sum(resultProb), numpy.sum(resultProb)))` gives the result: `Sum test: 0.9999999999999992 - 1.0`

Comment: @michaPau: I found cases where np.sum is not as precise as the Kahan sum, e.g. `a = [1000000000000000.0] + [1.0/1024.0] * 1024`.  – Actually there are two problems: The input numbers (such as 0.1) may not be represented exactly, and truncating of significant digits may occur during the summation.

Answer (score 4):

When using `numpy`, you should try to avoid for loops and instead favor vectorized operations.

This means that once you have extracted the desired data from your external data-structure, you store it in an `np.ndarray` and work forward from there. In your specific case, this is as simple as dividing the entire array with its sum; which is easily written:

```
def make_probabilities(data) -> np.ndarray:
    strengths = np.array([item['strength'] for item in data])
    return strengths / strengths.sum()
```

Note that:

- the division will be performed element-wise (this is know as [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in `numpy`);
- division by 0 will return an array of `np.nan` and `np.random.choice` will then only return the first element; you may want to account for that depending on your use-case.

Comment: Far better – I already had the feeling that I'm missing some NumPy-ness!

Comment: @MartinR But your answer is perfect from a pure Python perspective. It's just that using numpy all the way down, we should benefit from kahan summation without even knowing it exist.